# ORA-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am connected to a database using SQL Developer.

I can make queries, but to "`open description in popup`" on a stored procedure, it throws an "`Object not found`" message. If I try to open the browser options: Views, Procedures, Functions, Materialized Views, it throws the error

> ```
>  ORA-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested".
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, to post on SO, you need to post your question in english. (Translation for OP: Este sitio require que las preguntas se hagan en inglés, por favor). And for editors: the consensus appears to be that we should not attempt to translate OP's question ourselves: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: For some reason I cannot find any of the options you describe in my sqldeveloper instance. What version are you using?

Comment: it's usually b/c you're using a newer version of SQL Developer against a much older, and no longer supported version of Oracle Database - like SQL Developer v4.1 connected to Oracle 9iR2 database. the jdbc driver is asking something in a way the db doesn't understand.

Comment: im using  sqldeveloper  4.1.0.19

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - it worked for me after switching to [3.2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-v322-2080107.html), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your version of SQL Developer is using a JDBC driver (12.2.1.0) that is speaking a dialect that your version of the database, does not understand.

You can try to use a thick client connection - where you would configure SQL Developer to use an 11.2.0.3 Instant Client to make the connection - and that might help - but it depends on just how old your database is.

Your other option is to use an older version of SQL Developer which ships with an older version of the JDBC driver.

Ideally you'll want to keep your databases updated to modern versions. That's the ultimate and hardest solution though.